# Javascript: why can't I wait for async task to finish using while loop?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

The goal of the following code is to fetch webpages from three sites specified on command line and to display them in the order specified on command line. My first solution (shown below) was to use while loop to wait for three async tasks to finish but the while loop keeps looping forever. I learned that the correct solution was to detect if variable "count" reached 3 inside each async task (also shown below but commented out), not outside async task. But I'm wondering why my initial solution does not work. Can someone point me to the right Javascript specification of something that explains the flaw of my initial solution? Thanks!

```
var http = require('http');
var bl = require('bl');
var url1 = process.argv[2];
var url2 = process.argv[3];
var url3 = process.argv[4];
var content1;
var content2;
var content3;
var count = 0;

http.get(url1, function (res) {
        res.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
                content1 = data.toString();
                count++;
//              if (count == 3) printAll();
        }));
});

http.get(url2, function (res) {
        res.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
                content2 = data.toString();
                count++;
//              if (count == 3) printAll();
        }));
});

http.get(url3, function (res) {
        res.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
                content3 = data.toString();
                count++;
//              if (count == 3) printAll();
        }));
});


function printAll() {
        console.log(content1);
        console.log(content2);
        console.log(content3);
}

// this while loop loops forever
while (count < 3) {
  console.log('waiting..');
};

printAll();
```

Comment: `setTimeout()` is asynchronous too. It doesn't pause the loop.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. But my question still remains.

Comment: setTimeout will not wait a second there. It will simply try to call null in one seconds time repeatedly, which is BAD. If you're going to do anything, then call something another function and use setTimeout there to continue checking using an if statement instead of a while. You should be using a callback though from an async function.

Comment: `setTimeout` is async; `while` is not. It will cycle a million times through the loop before the first `setTimeout` concludes. The correct way to use this is with [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: You should read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop, especially the part about run-to-completion.

Comment: I removed setTimeout() line from my code because it's not relevant here (but I'm thankful to all of you who pointed that out). The while loop can be empty and it still will never detect count reaching 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` is not the same as `sleep`. It's a way to set a callback to happen in x milliseconds. You're passing null as the callback, and infinitely looping in the `while` loop, never relinquishing the thread to the http calls.

**Edit**: I would recommend looking into the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library for doing things like "wait for these three callbacks to finish".

Comment: This is also called "run to completion".

Comment: …and even if it was `sleep`, it would still be blocking and never allow the async callbacks to increase the count.

Comment: I removed setTimeout() line from my code because it's not relevant here (but I'm thankful to all of you who pointed that out). The while loop can be empty and it still will never detect count reaching 3.

Comment: Think of it like a microphone. Your code is a DJ holding the mic and tells three people to go look at a web page and then announce on the mic when they're done doing so. However, the DJ never hands the mic to the three people, so they can never announce that they're done.

Comment: mdickin, thanks for explaining it in layman's words. I'm truly impressed by how my question was answered so quickly.

Comment: No problem. See my edit for a helper library for these kinds of things.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by using recursive function that call itself using setTimeout:

```
(function loop() {
   if (count < 3) {
       setTimeout(loop, 1000);
       console.log('waiting..');
   } else {
       printAll();
   }
})();
```